# Show a tooltip above a cell in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tooltip

I need to show a tooltip above (or below :) a cell when the user enter a wrong value in it (see the image below).
I have a tooltip, but I need a Point to display it at the right position, so I want to get a cell position. Do you know how to get this?

BUT, if you have a better solution to realize this behaviour, I'm open to all proposition (especially for the fact that the tooltip is not bind with the cell/Jtable/Panel and if I move/close/minmize my window the tooltip is display at the same position)

[image]

Thanks,
Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [getCellRect](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getCellRect%28int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: Yeah! It seems this can respond to my problem, thanks :)
Do you know a solution where the tooltip is link to the cell?

Answer (score 6):

Please refer below code snippet, and you'll get the solution

```
JTable table = new JTable() {
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        if (c instanceof JComponent) {
            JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
            jc.setToolTipText(getValueAt(row, column).toString());
        }
        return c;
    }
};
```

If you want to only show the specific cell, all you have to do is change the column param in the params of getValueAt(...) method to a specific column which contains that cell

Comment: This doesn't work if using the RowSorter, as components won't change order, but model data will.

Comment: Worked really well for me (without RowSorter)

Answer (score 2):

You have [an example of such feature](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#celltooltip) in the Swing components visual guide.

Edit: In fact, it is not really a tooltip that you need here, as the tooltip need to have the cursor positionned over the cell. You want to display the tooltip even if the cursor is outside the cell, right?

Anyway, an alternative solution is to change the background of the cell when the value entered by the user is invalid (in orange or red for example), and then add a "real" tooltip (using the link I provided) in order to give the user a complete error message.

Comment: Yes, it's not a "real" tooltip.
Your workaround could be fine. Do you how can I show a (real) tooltip when the user entering a value? (I'm in the setValueAt() method)

Answer (score 2):

Just use below code while creation of JTable object.

```
JTable auditTable = new JTable(){

            //Implement table cell tool tips.           
            public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
                String tip = null;
                java.awt.Point p = e.getPoint();
                int rowIndex = rowAtPoint(p);
                int colIndex = columnAtPoint(p);

                try {
                    //comment row, exclude heading
                    if(rowIndex != 0){
                      tip = getValueAt(rowIndex, colIndex).toString();
                    }
                } catch (RuntimeException e1) {
                    //catch null pointer exception if mouse is over an empty line
                }

                return tip;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get the value for the correct row if using RowSorter:

```
jc.setToolTipText(getValueAt(convertRowIndexToModel(row), column).toString());
```

Comment: no - a) that's setting the same tooltip for all cells b) doesn't solve the _above_ part