# JTable tooltip issue with display position

Tags: java, user-interface, tooltip

I have an issue with tooltip in JTable cell. In my custom cell renderer, a call to `setToolTipText` is made. But on hovering on to the table cell, the tooltip is not showing at its proper position, although the text is right. Any idea on how to set the position of the tootip for a table cell for cell renderer class.

P.S I can not post the actual code here.
Thanks

Edit: 
Sample code

```
import java.awt.Color;


import bibliothek.extension.gui.dock.theme.EclipseTheme;
import bibliothek.gui.DockController;
import bibliothek.gui.dock.DefaultDockable;
import bibliothek.gui.dock.SplitDockStation;
import bibliothek.gui.dock.common.CControl;
import bibliothek.gui.dock.common.CGrid;
import bibliothek.gui.dock.common.DefaultSingleCDockable;
import bibliothek.gui.dock.common.intern.CDockable;
import bibliothek.gui.dock.common.theme.ThemeMap;
import bibliothek.gui.dock.station.split.SplitDockProperty;
import bibliothek.gui.dock.station.stack.tab.DefaultMenuLineLayoutFactory;
import bibliothek.gui.dock.station.stack.tab.MenuLineLayout;
import bibliothek.gui.dock.station.stack.tab.MenuLineLayoutOrder;
import bibliothek.gui.dock.station.stack.tab.TabPane;
import bibliothek.gui.dock.station.stack.tab.MenuLineLayoutOrder.Item;
import bibliothek.gui.dock.util.AppletWindowProvider;

import javax.swing.*;

public class aaa {
    public static void main( String[] args ){

        try {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            AppletWindowProvider window = new AppletWindowProvider(frame);
            CControl control = new CControl(window,true);
            frame.add(control.getContentArea());
            control.setTheme(ThemeMap.KEY_ECLIPSE_THEME);
            CGrid grid = new CGrid(control);
                grid.add(10, 0, 62, 100, new DefaultSingleCDockable("AAA"));
                grid.add(10, 0, 62, 100, new MyDock());
            grid.add(0, 0, 38, 100, new DefaultSingleCDockable("CCC"));
            control.getContentArea().deploy(grid);
            frame.setBounds(20, 20, 400, 400);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

    private static class MyDock extends DefaultSingleCDockable {
        TestPane pane;
        public MyDock() {
            super("BBB");
            pane = new TestPane();
            add(pane);
        }
    }
}
```

And class TestPane

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 10);
        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            Object[] data = new Object[10];
            for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                data[col] = row + "x" + col;
            }
            model.addRow(data);
        }

        JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            public Point getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent event) {

                Point p = this.getMousePosition();

                try{
                    int x = event.getX();//p.x;
                    int y = event.getY();//p.y;
                    //System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$x :- "+x+" ,  y :- "+y);
                    return new Point(x,y);
                }catch(Exception e)
                {

                    System.out.println("Exception "+e.getMessage());

                }



                return new Point(10, 10);
            }
        };
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TestCellRenderer());

        add(new JScrollPane(table));

    }

    public class TestCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                                       boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setToolTipText("Banana @ " + value.toString());
            return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                    hasFocus, row, column);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the proper position for a tooltip

Comment: Post at least a piece of code (containing setToolTipText calling).

Comment: post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

Without any code example provided, I can say this:

Use set toolTipText as follows:

```
JTable table = new JTable() {
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        if (c instanceof JComponent) {
            JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
            jc.setToolTipText(getValueAt(row, column).toString());
        }
        return c;
    }
};
```

or you can use `MouseEvent` as proposed here:

```
JTable auditTable = new JTable(){

            //Implement table cell tool tips.           
            public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
                String tip = null;
                java.awt.Point p = e.getPoint();
                int rowIndex = rowAtPoint(p);
                int colIndex = columnAtPoint(p);

                try {
                    tip = getValueAt(rowIndex, colIndex).toString();
                } catch (RuntimeException e1) {
                    //catch null pointer exception if mouse is over an empty line
                }

                return tip;
            }
        };
```

For source of this code snippets, visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193762/show-a-tooltip-above-a-cell-in-a-jtable) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467093/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-a-cell-in-a-jtable) SO questions.